# Why precompile not working what I am doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to precompile my validation to faster results my I get everytime 20ms+. Doesnt matter if I use zod or VineJS. I tried vine but everytime I get 20ms+. I am doing precompile wrong ?

here is the link
https://vinejs.dev/docs/getting_started#pre-compiling-schema

Server.ts

```
import vine from '@vinejs/vine';
const app = express();

export const schemaTenantsAdmin = vine.object({
  email: vine.string().email(),
  password: vine.string().minLength(6).confirmed(),
  firstname: vine.string(),
  lastname: vine.string(),
  city: vine.string(),
  street: vine.string(),
  zipcode: vine.string(),
  category: vine.string(),
  company: vine.string(),
  domain: vine.string(),
  code: vine.number()
});
export const validatorVine = vine.compile(schemaTenantsAdmin);

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//Reduce Fingerprint
app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use(helmet());

// app.use(rateLimiter);

app.use('/api/auth', router_auth);

// Custom Error Handler
app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('SERVER LISTEN ON PORT 3000');
});
```

signup.ts

```
export const SignUpTenantsAdmin = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    await validatorVine.validate(req.body);
    
    res.send('x');
  } catch(e) {
    Sentry.captureException(e);
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).json(e);
  }
};
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong I compile it at start. But if I compile or not I get everytime 20ms+ and this can never be right this libary is much faster than express validator on benchmark and if I use express validator it takes 1-3ms.